# Time and particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time, quantum-information, particle-physics

What it is in basic particles that  make them propagate themselves through time or, basically, what brings that property known as Duration in a particle (wave)? I sense that this is somehow is based on the notion of timespace and, I guess, the same 'thing' that make particles exist from one moment to another, underlies their spatial nature.

Comment: What do you mean "propagate themselves through time"? What *else* could they do? And asking "what makes them exist" is not a physical question, in my opinion, but metaphysics, unanswerable by scientific inquiry. They *are*. That's a (more or less) empirical fact.

Comment: I've seen a similar question before, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @ HDE 226868 is right: this question is asked regularly, and it is systematically closed as "unclear what you are asking". Personally I think the fact that each massive particle is generating proper time justifies the question if there might be a physical relation between mass and time.

Comment: Jess Parker, you ask: what brings that property known as duration in a particle? The answer in short: Time. The proper time of particles is the only absolute (= observer-independent) value which is representing time.